# CSS styling on hover

Tags: css

I've got a CSS hover on my site here - http://www.match-a-match.com/site/users/ it's on the top right.

```
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

I want the content within the box tobe no wider than 240px

I tried adding:

```
max-width: 240px;
```

But this meant the box was 240px but the content still went across the whole screen. I can't figure out how to make the content fit the 240px box!

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

EDIT: Full Snippet with HTML

```
   <style>
    .dropdown {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        padding: 12px 16px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<body>

    <div class="dropdown">
        <span>Account Info / Sign In</span>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <?php session_start(); $sessData=! empty($_SESSION[ 'sessData'])?$_SESSION[ 'sessData']: ''; if(!empty($sessData[ 'status'][ 'msg'])){ $statusMsg=$ sessData[ 'status'][ 'msg']; $statusMsgType=$ sessData[ 'status'][ 'type']; unset($_SESSION[ 'sessData'][ 'status']); } ?>
            <div class="container">
                <?php if(!empty($sessData[ 'userLoggedIn']) && !empty($sessData[ 'userID'])){ include_once 'user.php'; $user=n ew User(); $conditions[ 'where']=a rray( 'id'=> $sessData['userID'], ); $conditions['return_type'] = 'single'; $userData = $user->getRows($conditions); ?>
                <h2>Welcome <?php echo $userData['first_name']; ?>!</h2>
                <div class="regisFrm">

                    <th><b>Id:</b>
                        <p>
                            <?php echo $userData[ 'id']; ?>
                        </p>
                    </th>
                    <th><b>Name:</b>
                        <p>
                            <?php echo $userData[ 'first_name']. ' '.$userData[ 'last_name']; ?>
                        </p>
                    </th>
                    <th><b>Email:</b>
                        <p>
                            <?php echo $userData[ 'email']; ?>
                        </p>
                    </th>
                    <th><b>Phone:</b>
                        <p>
                            <?php echo $userData[ 'phone']; ?>
                        </p>
                    </th>
                    <th><b>Main Position:</b>
                        <p>
                            <?php echo $userData[ 'main']; ?>
                        </p>
                    </th>
                    <th><b>Available:</b>
                        <p>
                            <?php echo $userData[ 'available']; ?>
                        </p>
                    </th>
                    <th><b>Additional Information:</b>
                        <p>
                            <?php echo $userData[ 'addt_info']; ?>
                        </p>
                    </th>

                    <br>

                    <form action="accepted_requests.php" method="post">

                        <input name="search" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $userData['id'] ?>">
                        <br>

                        <input type="submit" value="Accepted Requests" />

                    </form>
                    <form action="requests.php" method="post">

                        <input name="search" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $userData['id'] ?>">
                        <br>

                        <input type="submit" value="Pending Requests" />

                    </form>
                    <form action="declined_requests.php" method="post">

                        <input name="search" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $userData['id'] ?>">
                        <br>

                        <input type="submit" value="Declined Requests" />

                    </form>

                    <a href=update.php>Update Profile</a>
                    <br>
                    <a href="userAccount.php?logoutSubmit=1" class="logout">Logout</a>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <?php }else{ ?>
                <h2>Login to Your Player Account</h2>
                <?php echo !empty($statusMsg)? '<p class="'.$statusMsgType. '">'.$statusMsg. '</p>': ''; ?>
                <div class="regisFrm">
                    <form action="userAccount.php" method="post">
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL" required="">
                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="PASSWORD" required="">
                        <div class="send-button">
                            <input type="submit" name="loginSubmit" value="LOGIN">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <p>Don't have an account? <a href="registration.php">Register</a>
                        <p>You are currently trying to login as a player, if you are a club please click <a href="http://localhost/register/Clubs/index.php">here</a>
                        </p>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>

</body>

</nav>
<a href="#navPanel" class="navPanelToggle"><span class="fa fa-bars"></span></a>
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: can you add your code snippet with your html

Comment: Of course it's quite long but I'll add it in now:

Comment: @James is this text content which is overlapping. ?

Comment: Primarily, if you got to the site you can see it when you hover over, it is also forms and PHP functions running server side to send html back to the site to display.

Comment: Apologies pasted wrong link, correct one is now up, don't judge it yet it's only in test!

Comment: @James you have 2 issues on your webpage. The main form is broken outside the page and also the hover also is breaking down.? so do you want a solution for both of them .?

Comment: Both I guess but the hover is definitely more important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will solve your hover issue.

```
 .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
 }

 .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
    right: 0;
    }

 .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
 }
 .dropdown-content .container {
    width: 100% !important;
 }
```

if you want more width to the hover content, please use `left: -ve;` values to  `.dropdown-content` div.

Comment: That is spot on thank you! I'm not a CSS guy as you can tell, do you mind me asking what you did that made it work?

Comment: @James looks like he added `right: 0;` to `.dropdown-content {}` and added the `.dropdown-content .container { width: 100% !important }` style, too. Note that you should probably just delete the `!important` from that; it is dangerous and almost always unnecessary.

Comment: Thank @TylerH appreciated. Man I love this site!

Comment: what I did is just made your `.dropdown-content` position `right:0` so that made the div pop related to the right from your `.dropdown` and then made the `.container` dive width `100%` to its parent instead of your `    width: 80em;`. So now the child is full width as its `related` parent. so if you want more than its width you have to use `left: -ve;` value to the `.dropdown-content`. I hope this helps.

Comment: Makes sense thank you very much. Been scratching my head for ages on this one. I'll stick to my databases from now on!

Comment: @James  yes, please do remove `!important` from that. i just put in my console to check and paste to you. But if your native code is overwriting my code then feel free to use `!important`

Answer (score 1):

I have created a working `codepen` for you: https://codepen.io/Omi236/pen/gRZYQZ See if it helps.

```css
.dropdown {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
  background: #ccc;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
  background: #0099ff;
  max-width: 240px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#">Hover Over</a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"></a>Link 1</li>
      <li><a href="#"></a>Link 2</li>
      <li><a href="#"></a>Link 3</li>
      <li><a href="#"></a>Link 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you I appreciate that, however if you go to http://www.match-a-match.com/site/users/ you can see it still doesn't sit within the 240px box it goes well outside it.

Comment: Happy to see that your problem is solved. If you feel appropriate kindly vote up to my answer :)

Comment: Thanks for telling me :)

Answer (score 0):

When looking at your site, I find the following:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1680px)
  .container {
    width: 80em;
}
```

This is way too much. Something like 20em will make it all fit.

Comment: Thank you I'll try this now